# ALAssetsLibrary invalid or null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetsgroup

I get the following error message : `invalid attempt to access <ALAssetPrivate: 0xa4a1ed0> past the lifetime of its owning ALAssetsLibrary` when I try to create custom Image Picker.

I used this [APPLE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135) sample to create this app. The sample Apple app works perfectly. But when I copied that sample code to my app it get the above error message.

Please can someone help me why this error comes & `ALAssetsGroup` become null.

Comment: Add the code where you get the crash and show how that code is related to the Apple sample.

Comment: Here is my question I asked before. But no answer yet
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654784/alassetsgroup-become-null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer for this problem. The problem is my ALAssetsLibrary I used got null by ARC. The solution is, add this static method instead of ALAssets Library..

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library; 
}
```

[Source](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/15/solve-xcode-error-invalid-attempt-to-access-alassetprivate-past-the-lifetime-of-its-owning-alassetslibrary/)